# Creating a wizard in C#

Tags: visual-studio, wizard

I would like to create a wizard to guide a user through some steps in order to create a document based on a template. I found this solution in msdn:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59(v=vs.80).aspx
```

The problem is that this tutorial creates a wizard as a New Item or New Project in Visual Studio. But I would like a standalone application, one in which my user can run the wizard without having Visual Studio.